# r dplyr text mining Error in eval(rhs, env, env) : object 'score' not found

Tags: r, function, dplyr, text-mining

I'm currently working on an R project and I was defining a function that would perform text mining on a specific dataset.

The general idea is to have a function that counts the number of the text mined and multiply that number with each text's score.

So far I've defined the function with :

```
function_a <- function(data, dict) {
  data %>% inner_join(dict) %>% count(word) %>% n*score
}
```

I am trying to calculate the score by multiplying the number of word appearances with its weightage but I got an error:

```
Error in eval(rhs, env, env) : object 'score' not found
```

Does this mean I have to define score as a function variable? Because it is a column within the dictionary.

Would greatly appreciate any help and insight into this issue. Thank you!

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only reference column variables like `score` in `dplyr` functions like `select`, `inner_join`, and so on. You tried to reference to `score` outside of a `dplyr` function, so R is looking for a variable called `score` and can not find it. The solution is to use `score` inside a dplyr function.

Here is an alternative way that should achieve your result by grouping by `word` and using `summarise` to get the word count:

```
 function_a <- function(data, dict) {
   data %>% inner_join(dict) %>% group_by(word) %>% summarise(WeightedCount = n()*score[1])
 }
```